# Any physical benefits to acne? Does the oil keep skin from wrinkling & sagging in the future? Can it prevent razor-burn & dandruff now?

Tags: acne, wrinkles, shaving-razor-burn, dandruff, dermatochalasis-saggy

I have cystic acne... and I'm 29. It's not all that fun.

I'm trying to be optimistic since no matter what I do I can't get rid of it. So... **Are there any benefits to having acne?** (I'm reaching for the stars, I know, but a girl has got to try to see the silver-lining!)

For instance:

**1. Does the oil act as a lubricant to prevent "razor-burn" when shaving?**

**2. Does the oil prevent dandruff?**

**3. Will all this oil cause my skin to look more "youthful" in the future, i.e. I won't have as much wrinkles?**

**4. Will it delay the process of skin-sagging, and keep it taut for longer?**

Answer (score 2):

According to this study [1](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ca.22571/abstract) those of us with oily skin may have less forehead wrinkles.