# Is frequent steaming of the face (like in a sauna) an effective way to open up skin pores and detox? Hydrogen Peroxide prevent acne?

Tags: acne, hydrogen-peroxide, detox-purge, pores, steam

**For those who suffer from acne -- is frequent exposure to steam an effective way to keep the skin clean?**

My understanding is heat opens up the skin-pores, and the skin pores are better able to detox, i.e. divulge their bacteria, that way?

I**s applying hydrogen peroxide with a Q-tip to each pimple, cyst, black head, a good way to clear up individual blemishes quickly?** Or is that not such a great idea?

Comment: Detoxing is nonsense invented by people selling snake oil, and I doubt that hydrogen peroxide will accomplish anything at all.  Acne treatments are usually pretty effective these days. See a dermatologist.

Comment: @CareyGregory -- I'd like to refer you to https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/9514/any-physical-benefits-to-acne-does-the-oil-keep-skin-from-wrinkling-sagging-i so you know what treatments I've tried.... and that, they actually are not effective for everyone. Just because they are effective for you, doesn't mean it works for everyone. I have seen a dermatologist for over 20 years, but thanks for your advice? Why wouldn't hydrogen-peroxide work if it kills bacteria?

Comment: Hydrogen peroxide kills living cells. It doesn't distinguish between bacteria and your own skin cells, which is why it's not recommended as a wound cleanser. It will likely do more harm than good. Second, the bacteria causing the acne aren't superficial, so the peroxide won't even reach them. Sorry dermatology hasn't been able to help you. I do hope you've seen more than one if the treatments have been ineffective. I assume you've tried them all because there are several.